# i try to create table in mysql with use of random() function.?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create able in mysql with random name of table name 
i try but cant created.
this is my code

```
$temp_table=rand(1000,9999);
$sql="CREATE TABLE $temp_table (FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT)";
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.
Try doing this instead:

```
$temp_table=randLetter().rand(1000,9999);
$sql="CREATE TABLE $temp_table (FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT)";

function randLetter()
{
  return chr(97 + mt_rand(0, 25));
}
```

Comment: thnk  karlingen this is work success fully thnks thnks thnks i really tnks u bcz this is in my  project  very use ful again very very thanks id   sumitdavdra@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the name:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE `$temp_table` (FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT)";
```

MySQL doesn't like numbers as identifiers.  (Or prefix with something like `table_`.)